# Deploy Angular Application in GitHub Pages

Tags: javascript, css, angular, git, github-pages

I have a GitHub pages website that uses a custom domain.

The domain serves a webapp made in Angular but when I access my domain the .js and .css files are not loading and on DevTools/Network I see a 404 Not Found per each .js or .css file I have on the branch assigned to the GitHub pages domain.

[image: Js and CSS file on my gh-pages branch]

[image: Error shown on DevTools Network tab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a common problem in Angular. When you generate the bundles you need to use:

```
ng build --prod --base-href ./
```

to set base-href to the root folder containing the bundles. Or if you already deployed the project just edit index.html and change the base tag to

```
 <base href="./">
```

More information in [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#deploy-to-github-pages).